# Excel header with a time converts to a date time header in Power Bi

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, data-modeling

I have an Excel spreadsheet which I am importing into Power Bi.

The columns look like so:

[image]

Every time it gets imported, the time headers get altered to this:
[image]

How do I stop Power Bi automatically adding the random `31/12/1899` dates?

Comment: Are the headers actual time values?

Comment: Is the data in Excel an actual  **Table**?

Comment: Ah silly mistake! @RonRosenfeld I realised it wasn't an actual table so that's why the headers weren't getting read as actual times.

Comment: How did you manage to get the times as time values then.  Usually, when you create a **Table**,  column headers get converted to text, which import into Power Bi without a change.

Comment: Yes you're correct, its been made as a table now, and it converts it to text. Cheers